# parsing text with php

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, text

```
01/01/2017 00:00:00 Entry Message 1 : TEXT1  Message 2 : TEXT1  Message 3 : TEXT1  Message 4 : TEXT1 
01/01/2017 00:00:00 Entry2 Message 1 : TEXT1  Message 2 : TEXT1  Message 3 : TEXT1  Message 4 : TEXT1

I need to parse the above text so that the outcome is an array for each row as such: 
    [0](
        [RandomString] => Entry
        [Message 1] => TEXT1
        [Message 2] => TEXT1  
        [Message 3] => TEXT1 
        [Message 4] => TEXT1 
        )
    [1](
        [RandomString] => Entry2
        [Message 1] => TEXT1
        [Message 2] => TEXT1  
        [Message 3] => TEXT1 
        [Message 4] => TEXT1 
        )
```

What I have right now is I can parse a single line which returns each field as an array element (note theres 2 spaces after each ‘TEXT1’ field )

```
$text = preg_split("@[\s+ 　]@u", $string);

Array\n(\n    [0] => 01/01/2017\n    [1] => 01/01/2017\n    [2] => Entry\n    [3] => Message\n    [4] => 1\n    [5] => :\n    [6] => TEXT1\n
```

Anyone know how id achieve this?